# HTML + CSS: take all available viewpoer

Tags: html, css, liquid-layout

I'm trying to make liquid HTML layout with header (taking all available width and 130px height), 2 columns (1: 300px width all possible height, 2: all available width after column 2 took its 300px and 15-20px margin between them).

Atm I've got this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">
      <!-- .... -->
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="left-column">
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 500px;
}

body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right-column {
  margin-left: 315px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The question is: are there any better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a fairly standard setup, I'm guessing the borders are just to see what is going on with the layout.  What aspects do you want to change?  NB while checking what you've got already, I added a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/qAmhJ/

Comment: yeah, borders are just to see whats going on. what  i'm bothered about are those left: 0; right: 0 maybe somehow padding/margin should be tweaked to make width: 100% work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your HTML and created this fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/RdQJY/1/. I didn't use any of your CSS though - I just don't like positioning used in the way you are using it, so decided to write it from scratch (sorry about that). The lorem ipsum text is just there as a placeholder - if you remove it, you'll see that the divs will occupy the whole window. Hope this helps!

P.S.: the only drawback to my method of having equal-height columns is that there is no easy way to apply a bottom border to them.

Comment: yes! exactly what i needed. i didn't like that bunch of position: absolute and and left/right: 0. thank you!